# Client network and server network in c sharp

Tags: c#, visual-studio, chat

me and my friends are currently trying to build a chat application with c sharp in visual studio .
while doing that we bumped into the words "client network" and "server network" .
I ve been told that those are two dll files that provides a connection between my client , server and database . Can anyone explain to me what should these dll files contain and how to they contribute to our chat application ( I am still a beginner ) 
Thank you so much !

Comment: There aren't specific dlls required to do client/server communication. If you've encountered these phrases, it's likely in relation to a *specific*, non-essential library/framework that's being used in some particular context. So it would help if you could *link* to where you encountered these phrases.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever to be honest that s what our professor pointed for us ( or at least what i understood ) but thanks for the explanation !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you want to solve the communication between the client and the server.
I recommend that you use socket to realize the connection between server and client, and

create two DLL files to facilitate program reference.

It will be explained in detail below.

(1) ClientCommunication.dll

1: Establish a Socket object;

2: Use the Connect() method of the socket object to send the connection request to the server with the EndPoint object created above as a parameter;

3: If the connection is successful, use the Send() method of the socket object to send information to the server;

4: Use the Receive() method of the socket object to receive the information sent by the server;

5: Be sure to close the socket after the communication is over

(2) ServerCommunication.dll

1: Establish a Socket object;

2: Bind EndPoint with the Bind() method of the socket object;

3: Use the Listen() method of the socket object to start listening;

4: Accept the connection to the client, use the socket object's Accept() method to create a new socket object for communicating with the requesting client;

5: Use the new socket object to receive and send messages.

ServerCommunication.dll contains ServerSocket.cs
ServerSocket.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ServerCommunication
{
   public class ServerSocket
    {
        static Socket serverSocket;
        public static void StartListening(IPAddress ip, int port) 
        {

            serverSocket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint point = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);
            serverSocket.Bind(point);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}Listen Success", serverSocket.LocalEndPoint.ToString());
            serverSocket.Listen(10);
            Thread myThread = new Thread(ListenClientConnect);
            myThread.Start();
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
         static void ListenClientConnect()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.Accept();
                clientSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Server Say Hello"));
                Thread receiveThread = new Thread(ReceiveMessage);
                receiveThread.Start(clientSocket);
            }
        }
        static void ReceiveMessage(object clientSocket)
        {
            Socket myClientSocket = (Socket)clientSocket;
            while (true)
            {

                try
                {
                    //clientSocket accept
                    byte[] result = new byte[1024];
                    int receiveNumber = myClientSocket.Receive(result);
                    Console.WriteLine("Receive client{0}news{1}", myClientSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString(), Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result, 0, receiveNumber));
            }
                catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                myClientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                myClientSocket.Close();
                break;
            }
        }
        }
}
}
```

ClientCommunication.dll contains ClientSocket.cs
ClientSocket.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClientCommunication
{
   public class ClientSocket
    {
       static byte[] result = new byte[1024];
        public static void StartClient(IPAddress ip, int port)
        {

            Socket socketClient = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint point = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);

            try
            {
                socketClient.Connect(point);
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully connected to server!");
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect to the server, please press enter to exit!");
                return;
            }
            //clientSocket accept 
            int receiveLength =   socketClient.Receive(result);

            Console.WriteLine("Receive server message:{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result, 0, receiveLength));

            // clientSocket send        
            try
            {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);    
                    string sendMessage = "client send Message Hellp" + DateTime.Now;
                    socketClient.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sendMessage));
                    Console.WriteLine("Send message to server:{0}" + sendMessage);
                }
                catch
                {
                    socketClient.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    socketClient.Close();                  
                }

            Console.WriteLine("After sending, press enter to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();   

        }
}
}
```

The specific use is as follows:

Server,cs  code:

```
using ServerCommunication;
using System.Net;

namespace Server
{
    class Server
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");           
            int port = 8885;
            ServerSocket.StartListening(ip,port);
        }
    }
}
```

Client.cs  code:

```
using ClientCommunication;
using System.Net;

namespace Client
{
    class Client
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            int port = 8885;
            ClientSocket.StartClient(ip,port);

        }
    }
}
```

Operation results:

Server:

[image]

Client:

[image]

Comment: @Zorghost, If this helps you or solve your problem, you can mark it as an answer.